# CiviCRM Bulk Email always shows [Civimail Draft] before the subject

Tags: civimail

When I send a email using the Bulk Mail facility of CiviCRM the subject line is always preceded by the text [Civimail Draft]. I must be doing something wrong but I am not sure what it is.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the final version, you are sending a draft. This is meant to be used to send to you and a few other testers.

The final "official" version is sent when you go to the next step and schedule to send it.

You will need to set up a cron to process the scheduled mailings and send them

Comment: You are exactly right. I was mistaken since I had sent a test email and then sent the final version but my email client aggregated the two and it appeared as if the final version had the [CiviMail Draft] prefix. It works just fine and exactly as designed. Apologies!